# Get gnome default terminal history from Zsh terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, zsh

Before ZSH, I used default Gnome terminal. I am using the ZSH terminal when I try use history cmd (in ZSH terminal) it only shows the ZSH session cmd history.

Now the question is how do I get the gnome default terminal history using the ZSH terminal session?

Answer (score 1):

If you want history to be saved in zsh, set history according to [zsh's guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l17). History file does not have special format (unless `EXTENDED_HISTORY` opt is set), so you can just point it to default bash `.history` file so they can be used together.

example `.zshrc` setting:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
```